# Locking the mouse cursor within a specified window on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mouse

I am looking for a program that can lock the mouse cursor within a specified window on Ubuntu 14.04 (using KDE). Ideally I should be able to enable/disable the locking using a keyboard shortcut.

On Windows 7, I use [WMC](http://veeteesoftware.blogspot.com/2008/11/wmc-1233.html). It's free, portable, only 56 KB and add an icon tray:

[image]

I am basically looking for an alternative for Ubuntu.

Comment: Under X11, this is called *grabbing the pointer*. It's usually the application owning the window that does it (the window grabs the mouse pointer), but it should be possible for another application to do it, since X doesn't really track window owners.

Comment: My window manager (Sawfish) has this as a built-in function. I presume that you're using Metacity, which is the default window manager on Ubuntu? The distribution is irrelevant here, as with almost every Linux question — what's relevant is which software you want to interoperate with, in this case the window manager or desktop environment.